# Prove that $f$ is continuous over $\cup _{i=1}^m F_i$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Problem:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ and let $F_i$ be a collection of closed sets such that $f|_{F_i}$ is continuous for each $i$ . Prove that $f$ is continuous over $\cup_{i=1}^m F_i$ ;$X,Y$ are metric spaces.

My attempt: Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\cup_{i=1}^m F_i$ such that $x_n\to x$. Since we have finite number of closed sets we must have one $F_i$ such that $F_i$ will contain infinitely many terms of the sequence i.e $F_i$ will contain a subsequence say $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$. Also $x_{n_k}\to x$. As $F_i$ is closed  so $x\in F_i$. As $f|_{F_i}$ is continuous then $f|_{F_i}(x_{n_k})\to f(x).$

But still I could not complete the proof.How to show that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$?

Comment: Hint: Fix $\epsilon>0$, for each $1\le k\le m$, you can choose $N_k$ such that for each $n>N_k$ satisfying $x_n\in F_k$, we have $d(f(x_n),f(x))<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C\subset Y$ be closed in $Y$. We need to show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$.
$$f^{-1}(C)=\bigcup_{i=1}^nf^{-1}|_{F_i}(C)$$ Since each $f^{-1}|_{F_i}(C)$ is closed. So, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an alternative approach for general topological space just in case you're interested. Following this link [For closed subsets $A,B \subseteq X$ with $X = A \cup B$ show that $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/continuity-of-function-where-the-functions-restricted-to-certain-closed-subspace), it shows that your statement is true for $m=2$. You can extend the case by induction.

Note: Your statement is also true if the sets are all open instead of closed.